# Adjust lithium BMS over discharge voltage

Tags: bms, lithium, over-discharge

I have a few 2-series lithium battery protection modules coming from different sources, but all of them are the same classic chinese ones based on Hycon's HY2120 chip.

These are all shuting down at around 7V when at discharge mode, being every lithium cell still at 3.5V.

At all sources i read, voltage over discharge threhold cut-off are about 3V for each individual cell, so it should be 6V for the 2-series module.

What would be the cause of my modules shutting down at 7V instead of 6V?

Comment: Are you measuring the voltage in use, or afterward? Are you checking the individual cell voltages?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting measuring the voltages while in use.
BMS shutoff is actually at 6.6V, 3.3V per cell. I should have been aware about battery self-recovery seconds after shutoff. However, 6.6V still a bit too high

Comment: Are you inferring or measuring the individual cell voltages?

Comment: As well as voltage recovery aspects, there is little energy below say 3.3V loaded. Look at data sheet curves. Cell whole of life Ahcapacity is often much improved by cut off slightly higher with minimal loss of capacity.